# pega-web-tomcat container not starting with | Problem during method invocation (doPostInner)

Tags: kubernetes, tomcat, deployment, pega

**Pega helm deployment failing**

The following represents my values (yaml) file for helm deployment containing a minimal deployment as I have only three nodes in my cluster with 32GB each node.  I have an external kafka deployment. and am letting pega build the Cassandra cluster for dss data store.

```
---
global:
  provider: "k8s"

  deployment:
    name: "dev1"

  actions:
    execute: "install"

  storageClassName: ""
  jdbc:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.xxx:5432/Pega"
    driverClass: "org.postgresql.Driver"
        driverUri: "https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.5.4.jar"
    username: "pega"
    password: "rules"
    external_secret_name: ""
    connectionProperties: ""
    rulesSchema: "rules"
    dataSchema: "data"
    customerDataSchema: "customer"

  customArtifactory:
    authentication:
      basic:
        username: ""
        password: ""
      apiKey:
        headerName: ""
        value: ""
      external_secret_name: ""
    enableSSLVerification: true
    certificate:

  docker:
    registry:
      url: "https://hub.docker.com"
      username: "myrepo"
      password: "xxx"
    imagePullSecretNames: []
    pega:
      image: "myrepo/my-pega:23"

  utilityImages:
    busybox:
      image: busybox:1.31.0
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    k8s_wait_for:
      image: Pegasystems/k8s-wait-for
      imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
      # waitTimeSeconds: 2
      # maxRetries: 1

  upgrade:
    kube-apiserver:
      serviceHost: "https://192.168.1.xxx"
      httpsServicePort: "16443"

  compressedConfigurations: false

  tier:
    - name: "k8s-dev"
      nodeType: "Stream,BackgroundProcessing,WebUser,Search,DataFlow"
      requestor:
        passivationTimeSec: 900
      service:
        httpEnabled: true
        port: 80
        targetPort: 8080
        tls:
          enabled: false
          external_secret_name: ""
          keystore:
          keystorepassword:
          port: 443
          targetPort: 8443
          cacertificate:
          certificateFile:
          certificateKeyFile:
          traefik:
            enabled: false
            serverName: ""
            insecureSkipVerify: false

      ingress:
        domain: "web.k8s-dev.org.local"
        tls:
          enabled: false
          certificate:
          key:
          cacertificate:

      replicas: 1
      javaOpts: ""
      pegaDiagnosticUser: ""
      pegaDiagnosticPassword: ""

      volumeClaimTemplate:
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 5Gi

      deploymentStrategy:
        rollingUpdate:
          maxSurge: 1
          maxUnavailable: 0
        type: RollingUpdate

      livenessProbe:
        port: 8081

      hpa:
        enabled: false

      pdb:
        enabled: false
        minAvailable: 1

cassandra:
  enabled: true
  persistence:
    enabled: true
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: "4Gi"
      cpu: 2
    limits:
      memory: "8Gi"
      cpu: 4

dds:
  port: "9042"
  username: "dnode_ext"
  password: "dnode_ext"
  clientEncryption: false
  trustStore: ""
  trustStorePassword: ""
  keyStore: ""
  keyStorePassword: ""
  external_secret_name: ""
  asyncProcessingEnabled: false
  keyspacesPrefix: ""
  extendedTokenAwarePolicy: false
  latencyAwarePolicy: false
  customRetryPolicy: false
  customRetryPolicyEnabled: false
  customRetryPolicyCount: 1
  speculativeExecutionPolicy: false
  speculativeExecutionPolicyEnabled: false
  speculativeExecutionPolicyDelay: 100
  speculativeExecutionPolicyMaxExecutions: 2
  jmxMetricsEnabled: true
  csvMetricsEnabled: false
  logMetricsEnabled: false

pegasearch:
  image: "myrepo/my-pega-search:23"
  memLimit: "3Gi"
  replicas: 1

installer:
  image: "myrepo/my-pega-installer:23"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  adminPassword: "passwordX"
  upgrade:
    upgradeType: "in-place"
    targetRulesSchema: "rules"
    targetDataSchema: "data"
    pegaRESTUsername: ""
    pegaRESTPassword: ""

hazelcast:
  image: "YOUR_HAZELCAST_IMAGE:TAG"
  clusteringServiceImage: "YOUR_CLUSTERING_SERVICE_IMAGE:TAG"
  enabled: false
  clusteringServiceEnabled: false
  migration:
    initiateMigration: false
    migrationJobImage: "YOUR_MIGRATION_JOB_IMAGE:TAG"
    embeddedToCSMigration: false
  replicas: 3
  username: ""
  password: ""
  external_secret_name: ""

stream:
  enabled: "false"
  bootstrapServer: ""
  securityProtocol: PLAINTEXT
  trustStore: ""
  trustStorePassword: ""
  keyStore: ""
  keyStorePassword: ""
  jaasConfig: ""
  saslMechanism: PLAIN
  streamNamePattern: "pega-{stream.name}"
  replicationFactor: "1"
  external_secret_name: ""
```

**Problem Description**
I can produce the entire logs if needed as the system is almost getting to complete start.  I am getting the following log output indicating a **NullPointerException** occurring when the web container is starting.

Kubernetes: microk8s v: v1.27.8
StorageClass: nfs

Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-91-generic x86_64)

System information as of Sun Jan 21 10:22:24 PM UTC 2024

System load:           0.6806640625
Usage of /:            26.5% of 97.87GB
Memory usage:          18%
Swap usage:            0%
Processes:             223

```
21-Jan-2024 21:41:43.305 SEVERE [http-nio2-8080-exec-5] com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega. Problem during method invocation (doPostInner)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.PRSessionProviderImpl.borrowRequestor(PRSessionProviderImpl.java:740)
        at com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.PRSessionProviderImpl.borrowRequestor(PRSessionProviderImpl.java:755)
        at com.pega.pegarules.session.internal.PRSessionProviderImplForModules.borrowRequestor(PRSessionProviderImplForModules.java:60)
        at com.pega.platform.web.request.internal.ResponseProcessorImpl.getBrowserRequestor(ResponseProcessorImpl.java:222)
        at com.pega.platform.web.request.internal.ResponseProcessorImpl.getStream(ResponseProcessorImpl.java:184)
        at com.pega.platform.web.request.internal.ResponseProcessorImpl.getStatusPageStream(ResponseProcessorImpl.java:174)
        at com.pega.platform.web.request.internal.ResponseProcessorImpl.writeStatusOutput(ResponseProcessorImpl.java:191)
        at com.pega.pegarules.web.impl.WebStandardImpl.doPostInner(WebStandardImpl.java:484)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrap.invokeMethod(PRBootstrap.java:388)
        at com.pega.pegarules.internal.bootstrap.PRBootstrap.invokeMethodPropagatingThrowable(PRBootstrap.java:430)
        at com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega.invokeMethodPropagatingThrowable(AppServerBridgeToPega.java:225)
        at com.pega.pegarules.boot.internal.extbridge.AppServerBridgeToPega.invokeMethod(AppServerBridgeToPega.java:274)
        at com.pega.pegarules.internal.web.servlet.WebStandardBoot.doPost(WebStandardBoot.java:164)
        at com.pega.pegarules.internal.web.servlet.WebStandardBoot.doGet(WebStandardBoot.java:121)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
        at com.pega.pegarules.internal.web.servlet.WebStandardBoot.service(WebStandardBoot.java:191)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:765)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1732)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1295)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint.setSocketOptions(Nio2Endpoint.java:339)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2Acceptor.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:479)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2Acceptor.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:415)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]; on the one hand, trimming down the Helm values to only the minimum needed to demonstrate the issue, and on the other, including enough of your Helm template code, Kubernetes YAML, and other artifacts you've written to show what might be wrong in that code?